Changing the name of lstlisting
Is it possible to change the name of the lstlisting environment from the listing package?

Please always include a short test document in your questions.

Instead of changing the name, you could just define a new listings environment and use this instead:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstnewenvironment{newname}[1][]{\lstset{#1}}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{newname}
source code
\end{newname}

\end{document}


OK, I'll do just that. Thanks
